# see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH libraries

Tags: environment-variables

As I know we can define the search path for additional non standard libraries using `export LD_LIBRAY_PATH`.

How can I see the list of these additional libraries after setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ls`:

```
(IFS=:; set -f; ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

Notice that there's no guarantee that a binary will not **ignore** your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; On linux, the `DT_RPATH` attribute from the ELF binary (but not `DT_RUNPATH`) will override `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See `man 8 ld.so` for all the details.

Also, the "paths" from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may contain `$ORIGIN`, `$LIB` or `$PLAFORM` tokens that will be expanded by the dynamic linker depending on the path of the program and its format.

The only way to automatically determine what libraries will be used by a program is to run `ldd your_program`. But don't do that with random binaries; it may be as dangerous as actually exec'ing the program.